# how to instantiate a class with result object in Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, instantiation

The documentation for  [result()](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html)  says that we can pass  the name of a class to instantiate for each result object: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html

I'm can't figure out correct way to do so.I need to pass few fields from the result object to the constructor.

> ```
> $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users;");
>
> foreach ($query->result('User') as $user)
> {
>
>   echo $row->name; // call attributes
>   echo $row->reverse_name(); // or methods defined on the 'User' class
> ```
>
> }

please let me know if there are better ways!

Comment: Never tried this, but shouldn't it be `echo $user->name` (and yes I see that it is the same in the documentation)

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

The object instantiated can't be passed any arguments, which means you need to create a method you can use to pass these fields to the object which is instantiated:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users;");

foreach ($query->result('User') as $user)
{

  $row->init_my_fields('field1', 'field2'); //instead of passing the fields through the __construct()
  echo $row->name; // call attributes
  echo $row->reverse_name(); // or methods defined on the 'User' class

}
```

Comment: Have you tested that? the idea of instantiating that way don't seem to be working.it didn't work in case of mine

Comment: How do you load the object you are trying to instantiate?

Comment: wanted to instantiate like in the documentation. ($query->result('User') as $user)... doesn't work .But finally accomplished by doing it in normal way.Any way thanks for your help.i've initialized the objects through methods. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a static Class method in your User class that creates a user or users instances. You will need to add the appropriate instance vars to the User class.

```
var $username = FALSE;
var $password = FALSE;

public static function get_user_by_id($id)
{
      $CI =& get_instance();
      $query = $CI->db->get_where('users', array('id' => $id));
      $user = $query->row(0, 'User');
      return $user;
}
```

In the example I'm getting a reference to the CodeIgniter instance to access the database. Since you can't access the database from a Class method since it is not an object instance.

Answer (score 0):

from codeigniter documentation

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users LIMIT 1;");
$row = $query->getRow(0, 'User'); // or ->row(0, 'User') in CI 3
```

from codeigniter /system/database/DB_result.php

```
public function custom_result_object($class_name)
{
    ...

    if ($_data !== NULL)
    {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $c; $i++)
        {
            $this->custom_result_object[$class_name][$i] = new $class_name();

            foreach ($this->{$_data}[$i] as $key => $value)
            {
                $this->custom_result_object[$class_name][$i]->$key = $value;
            }
        }

        return $this->custom_result_object[$class_name];
    }
    ...
}
```

I believe this means that CI define new class with empty constructor from the wanted class "should be available to instantiate in the scope" , and tries to set its properties with the values from the row result and then returns it